# Clear input field and enter new info using Watir? (Ruby, Watir)

Tags: ruby, watir

Pretty positive you have to use .clear, or maybe not as it doesn't seem to be working for me, maybe i'm just implementing it wrong I'm unsure.

Example:

```
browser.div(:id => "formLib1").clear.type("input", "hi")
```

Can anyone tell me how to simply clear a field then enter in a new string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming we are talking about a text field (ie you are not trying to clear/input a div tag), the `.set()` and `.value=` methods automatically clear the text field before inputting the value.

So one of the following would work:

```
browser.text_field(:id, 'yourid').set('hi')
browser.text_field(:id, 'yourid').value = 'hi'
```

Note that it is usually preferred to use `.set` since `.value=` does not fire events.

Comment: I doesn't work for me (element came from `iframe` , but I didn't really isolate the reason)

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue, and, for some reason, `.set()` and `.value=` were not available/working for the element.

The element was a Watir::Input:

```
browser.input(:id => "formLib1").to_subtype.clear
```

after clearing the field I was able to enter text.

```
browser.input(:id => "formLib1").send_keys "hi"
```

Comment: Note that once you convert the `Watir::Input` to a `Watir::TextField`, you can then call the `set` method - ie `browser.input(:id => "formLib1").to_subtype.set("hi")`. This would eliminate the need to manually call `clear`.

Comment: `send_keys` worked for me, but not yet `to_subtype.clear` (values unchanged). the element came from an `iframe`, but I still don't understand why `set`/`value=` aren't avaliable.

Comment: @JustinKo: that makes sense, but for me I still had to send `clear` for `set` to work.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and, for some reason, `.set()` and `.value=` were not available for the element.

The element was a Watir::HTMLElement:

```
[2] pry(#<Object>)> field.class
=> Watir::HTMLElement

field.methods.grep /^(set|clear)$/
=> []
```

I resorted to sending the backspace key until the value of the field was `""`:

```
count = 0
while field.value != "" && count < 50
  field.send_keys(:backspace)
  count += 1
end
field.send_keys "hi"
```